# Unit Test Moq System.NotSupportException

Tags: c#, moq

[This is the code and the error I'm getting while trying to Moq a service for a unit test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlZYe.png)

```cs
public async void GetDocumentForProjectStatusTest() 
{
    var _projectService = new Mock<ProjectService>();
    var testStatus = new ProjectStatus 
    {
        Id = 1,
        ReportingPeriodEndDatetime = new DateTime(2021, 1, 1),
        ReportingPeriodStartDatetime = new DateTime(2020, 10, 10)
    };

    _projectService.Setup(x =>
        x.GetProjectStatusByIdAsync(It.IsAny<int>
            ())).ReturnsAsync(Result.Success(testStatus));
}
```

`'Error: System.NotSupportedException: 'Unsupported expression: x => x.GetProjectStatusByIdAsync(It.IsAny<int>()) Non-overridable members (here: ProjectService.GetProjectStatusByIdAsync) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.'`

I am trying to Mock this service in my unit test but keep running into this. I've seen other questions like this around and have tried to adjust based on those answers but haven't gotten it to work. If anyone can help could they please explain along with their solution? I'd love to better understand this, thanks!!

Comment: Please put your code and errors into your question in text format.  See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You cannot mock a concrete implementation.  You can only mock an interface.

Comment: My bad, I put in the Code and Error!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to mock a concrete implementation, which means you're not coding against abstractions, which means your dependencies can't be mocked. Make ProjectService implement an interface, swap all usages to that interface; prod injects a ProjectService instance, and tests can mock the interface and inject & setup and verify that mock.